# passport Js:redirect to another url with data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

From the passportjs  documentation, I can redirect to  a URL

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Is it possible `successRedirect` should be another different domain suppose 
my authentication is in `www.auth.com` after successful login I want to redirect to `www.customer.com/callback`  with the data from `www.auth.com`.

It's actually like Facebook authentication with callback URL after successful login facebook `POST` data to the callback URL

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) { //will handle if user fails to enter valid credentials
  return res.render('login', {
    message: 'Login Page Renderd...'
  });
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/profile', //will be redirected to `/profile` route after successful login
  failureRedirect: '/login' //will be redirected to `/login` route for failure
}));

app.get('/profile', function(req, res) { //will handle if user enter valid credentials means user logged in successfully
  return res.status(200).send('User Logged in successfully...');
});
```

[Passport-Facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) we need to define callback url for successful & failure of authentication same as [Passport-Local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local)

Comment: This solution only redirect to the pages in the same domain but i want to redirect to page in the another domain

Comment: You can pass the the URL in state param, and then use that to redirect later in callback.

Comment: @iambatman, You can not redirect to another application from the server-side code.
You can get a response from the server then check whether is OK (200) then redirect to another application. (Sorry for the late response) :-)

Comment: @lone_worrior, yes we can do that. but passing the parameter in URL while login is incorrect in order to create a good application.